# How to choose specific algorithm on Amazon Machine Learning or another cloud platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, cloud

Is is possible to run some specific machine learning algorithms on Amazon Machine Learning? For me it's seems like it works like a black box: you put data there and get some performance without algorithm selection, parameters tuning, etc.

By the way, is it possible somewhere to run specific machine learning algorithm in cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Amazon Machine Learning FAQ [here](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/faqs/), they state that the algorithm being used in this package is logistic regression.

If you want something more sophisticated you'd have to do more work yourself, such as setting up the necessary packages on and EC2 or EMR cluster.